# How to drop rows from a GeoPandas dataframe that are raising errors, in this case: TopologyException, Ring Self-intersection

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to find the points from a geopandas frame that are inside the polygons from another geopandas frame. The code that I am using is the following:

```
points[points.geometry.within(polygons.unary_union)]
```

Most of the times it works, but for one file it gives me this error:

```
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point -71.126795046686823 42.767412284376533 at -71.126795046686823 42.767412284376533
```

this error is raised when I do

```
polygons.unary_union
```

My understanding is that (at least) one of the polygons is invalid.

I don't mind if I drop some polygons, I don't need to be 100% accurate. The question is: How do I drop the rows from a geopandas frame that are raising the TopologyException

The polygon dataframe is coming from: https://docs.digital.mass.gov/dataset/massgis-data-2016-land-coverland-use

The particular shp file with problems: http://download.massgis.digital.mass.gov/shapefiles/lclu2016/LCLU_R02C18.zip

Answer (score 10):

You can check for valid geometries using [`is_valid`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=is_valid#geopandas.GeoSeries.is_valid).

You could use the `buffer(0)` trick ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311210/2856), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/243144/2856)) to repair the invalid geometries:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp)

invalid_geom = ~gdf['geometry'].is_valid
gdf.loc[invalid_geom, 'geometry'] = gdf.loc[invalid_geom, 'geometry'].buffer(0)
```

If you prefer to drop them:

```
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf['geometry'].is_valid, :]
```

Comment: Very good and useful answer, I wish the OP understood how to accept it.